# Setup argment matcher with IEnumerable in NSubstitue

Tags: c#, ienumerable, nsubstitute, argument-matching

I am working on a unit test for a project and I cannot figure out how to get NSubstitute to work the way I would expect it to. The issue I am having is that the code I was to substitute is in a while loop and depending on what is returned from the substituted value determines if the loop continues.

What I would like to do is have Process() return a different result based on what is passed in. I have tried

```
api.Process(Arg.Is<IEnumerable<int>>(new[] {1,2,3}, Arg.Any<bool>()).Returns(new ProcessingResult(){Success = true, IdsNotProcessed = List<int>{30}});
```

but it does not seems to work as processingResult comes back null because NSubstitue is not matching the argument.

```
    [Test]
    public void TestTwoLoops()
    {
        var api = Substitute.For<IApi>();
        api.Process(/*list containing 1,2,3*/, Arg.Any<bool>()).Returns(new ProcessingResult(){Success = true, IdsNotProcessed = List<int>{30}});
        api.Process(/*list containing 30*/, Arg.Any<bool>()).Returns(new List<int>{});

        var sut = new WidgetMaker(api);

        sut.MakeWidget();
    }

    public class WidgetMaker
    {
        public WidgetMaker(IApi api)
        {
            _api = api;
        }

        public void MakeWidgets(IEnumerable<int> widgetIds)
        {
            var idsToProcess = widgetIds.ToList();

            while(true)
            {
                if(!idsToProcess.Any())
                {
                    berak;
                }

                var processingResult = _api.Process(idsToProcess, false);

                if(processingResult.Success)
                {
                    idsToProcess.Clear();
                    idsToProcess.AddRange(processingResult.IdsNotProcessed);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private IApi _api;
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I was writing this question, the answer came to me, but I have a feeling others might find this helpful.

Using the overload that accepts a predicate and using the SequenceEqualExtension method with a parameter of new[] {/*values I want to be input*/}

```
api.Process(Arg.Is<IEnumerable<int>>(x => x.SequenceEqual(new[] {1,2,3}, Arg.Any<bool>())).Returns(new ProcessingResult(){Success = true, IdsNotProcessed = List<int>{30}});
```